# php select options in different steps

Tags: php, forms, html-select

VERY basic question: I currently have the following (array?) for a select box within a form but I need to change the jump/step in numbers that appear in the drop down. At the moment it is in multiples of `100`, from `300-1500` but I need multiples of **100 up to 1000** and then **1250 and 1500**.

```
for($i = 300; $i <= 1500; $i += 100)
```

Comment: Not clear enough. You need to increase it with different values? What are the values? What would be the order ?

Comment: change `$i <= 1500` to `$i <= 1000` and get all values in `$options` array through foreach. Lastly, append 1250 and 1500 to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the function `range()` ?
You can configure start, end, and step.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: range has a fixed increment, hasn't it ?

Comment: The step means the fixed increment, but you can use `range()` for part of the loop with the first step/increment, then call `range()` again with different start and end and step to continue the loop as you wish.

Comment: sure, but after some reading i think even this would be possible:
$inc = 100;
foreach (range(300, 1500, $inc) as $number) {
    echo $number;
    if ($number >= 1000){$inc = 250}
}

Comment: Exactly, that's another way to do it which looks better for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
$step = 100;
for($i = 300; $i <= 1500; $i += $step){
if ($i >= 1000) {$step = 250}...
```

or

```
$inc = 100; 
foreach (range(300, 1500, $inc) as $number) 
{ 
echo "<Option>".$number."</Option>"; 
if  ($number >= 1000){$inc = 250} 
}
```

but i am not 100% sure if the second one works

Answer (score 0):

Just add the options from 100 to 1000 with a for loop and then add the other two options afterwards.

```
<select>
    <?php
        for($i = 100; $i <= 1000; $i+=100)
        {
            echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
    <option>1250</option>
    <option>1500</option>
</select>
```